# What inventions/technologies would have to be created to achieve apotheosis?

Tags: science-based, technology, economy, technological-development, psychology

*Apotheosis* is the highest point of development in technology or a society. What key milestones need to be reached in order to achieve this in the fields of:

- Chemistry
- Physics
- Biology
- Engineering
- Mathematics
- Psychology
- Philosophy
- Medicine
- Law and government

Comment: I believe you should be looking for "singularity" in the sense used by Kurzweil. The word "apotheosis" means literally becoming god, which is no good fit for technology. Also, your question is too broad.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! As has already been mentioned this is a really broad question, because you are looking at a lot of different fields. Furthermore it is opinion-based, as we have no idea what would be needed. Please take the tour and visit the help center to learn more about the site. You can use the "edit"-button to edit your question and narrow it down / explain in more detail what you are especially interested in. Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think many of those disciplines would appreciate an attempt to put a checkbox out there for "apotheosis."  Most of them involve discovery.  As we discover new things, the checkbox moves further out.

That being said, XKCD may have an answer for you:

[image: XKCD]

- Biology - prove everything psychology theorizes
- Chemistry - prove everything biology theorizes
- Physics - prove everything chemistry theorizes
- Mathematics - ... do more math stuffs.  Let's be honest, they're not really all that worried about proving everything physics theorizes.

Of course, you've also limited apotheosis to within each of these domains.  If you look at it on a grander style, to try to achieve the highest point of societal advancement, many wise men suggest a much shorter list.